# IE7 text being pushed down

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-float, internet-explorer-7

Here is my site:
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/ppp/welcome.html

In Firefox and IE8 it's fine, but in IE7 the down arrow image to the right of the big 'CHISTOPOL' heading is further down that it should be. It looks like its being pushed down a row, as if the 'CHISTOPOL' text is taking up 100% of the width.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: Please use a meaningful title.

Comment: in IE 7 your Chistopol-link takes the full line so the arrow goes to the next line, where it floats to the right as `float:right` does. Why the Chistopol-link takes the full line I don't really see, but it's clearly not meant to, and likely a IE7 `float` or `clear` bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what the problem is but it also happens in IE6.

You could apply the following CSS

```
#welcome-title-bottom {
    position:relative;
}
```

And then add `style="position:absolute;right:5px;"` to the "arrow" anchor and remove the `class="right"` which fixes the problem for me in IE6.

Personally, I try to avoid using CSS float when I can due to these sorts of cross browser layout issues.

Comment: "Personally, I try to avoid using CSS float when I can due to these sorts of cross browser layout issues." Agree, but personally I rather avoid archaic browsers that don't handle floats well (IE6 and IE7).

Comment: I dont know whats causing this issue but if absolute positioning is easier for cross browser issues ill just do it this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `width:auto` from `#welcome-title-bottom a` see if it helps.

Comment: It didnt work before as I added that to try and fix it. Thanks